# Scala comonads; Comonad laws?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, category-theory, comonad

So given this encoding of a comonad (see below) are the comonad laws above it correct? for some reason I don't think they are  from looking at them, and I know that heading off wrong from there will yield only bad road, so I'd appreciate the nudge, hint, help, answer what have you.

```
      /**
       * note: I think these are right
       * Comonad Laws
       * 
       * (i)   counit(cojoin(m))      == m
       * 
       * (ii)  >>(counit(m))(cojoin)  == m
       * 
       * (iii) cojoin(cojoin(m))      == >>(cojoin(m))(cojoin)
       * 
       */

        trait Comonad[M[_]] {

           // map
           def >>[A,B](a: M[A])(f: A => B): B

          // extract | coeta 
          def counit[A](a:M[A]): A

          // cobind | =<< | extend
          def coflatMap[A,B](ma:M[A])(f: M[A] => B): M[B]

          // coflatten | comu
         def cojoin[A](a: M[A]): M[M[A]]
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there. Both, `(i)` and `(iii)` are correct, but `(ii)` is wrong. You can spot the mistake because `(ii)` is not well typed: for `>>(counit(m)` the argument `counit(m)` has type `A` rather than `M[A]`.

The correct laws for your operations are:

```
   * (i)   counit(cojoin(m))      == m
   * 
   * (ii)  >>(cojoin(m))(counit)  == m
   * 
   * (iii) cojoin(cojoin(m))      == >>(cojoin(m))(cojoin)
```

Thus, for both `(i)` and `(ii)`, the law is that applying either `counit` or the "map" of `counit` to the result of a `cojoin` is equivalent to the identity function.

Comment: Apparently this has been "unaccepted", but no reason has been given. Did anyone spot a mistake perhaps?